# Will a 64-bit Unsigned Integer wrap around on 32-bit system?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, unsigned-long-long-int

Simple question, need an answer quickly please!

Take this situation on a 32-bit machine:

```
Unsigned long long n = 1;
n -= 2;
```

I know on a 64-bit machine, this would wrap around to the highest unsigned long long. But what would happen on a 32-bit machine, since the long long is stored as two separate words?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the implementation is conforming, then the same: it will correctly wrap around. I assume this is C; The C standard requires this behavior independently from the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

A 64 bit integer datatype behaves the same on all architectures, including 32 bit. If not, programming would be quite hard, wouldn't it?